# DDD and configuration

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository-pattern

How do I give access to user configured settings in DDD?

We have a configuration database which stores items as a bunch of key-value pairs. This doesn't really seem to fit the repository pattern, so how do I enable the user to access these configuration values?

Ideally I'd like to have separate classes for different groupings of configuration, ie.. BillingSettings, ReportSettings, TaxSettings.

It would seem odd to provide a separate repository for each of these, but I also want to maintain persistence ignorance for these settings classes.

What is the correct way of enabling access to configuration in DDD?

Answer (score 3):

What I typically do is just abstract the configuration using interfaces, e.g. `IBillingConfiguration`, `IReportConfiguration`, etc.  The implementations of these are then what get passed into the relevant methods (or injected into the relevant objects).

Where the values comes from then really shouldn't matter.  There are times when I do use a repository when storing the values in a database and then I'd have something like `IConfigurationPropertyRepository`.  It is somewhat of an awkward fit since a `ConfiruationProperty` does not quite feel like a first-class citizen in the Entity world but it does seem to get the job done.

I would return some implementation of a `IBillingConfiguration` that just gets the required property from an underlying collection or `ConfigurationProperty` objects.

The relevant `Get` and `Save` methods for each `I{Some}Configuration` would be implemented on the `ConfigurationPropertyRepository` so that I only get/save that subset of the properties that need to be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Is BillingSettings really an aggregate (or even a domain object) in your domain models? If not, it should not have a corresponding repository.

Most of the configrations are infrastructure-specific such as jdbc url, password and so on. You don't have to deal with them in the way of DDD. We may need a ConfigurationService support CRUD operations if the settings are stored in database and are allowed to be modified by users at runtime. But the ConfigurationService does not belong to the domain and this ordering bounded context, it's just an infrastructure service. We don't have to develop it in DDD way.

Update for @Kristof Jozsa's comment.

The settings are used to support an domain concept. The domain concept is abstract, and how to access settings is an implementation details.

```
class ExpirationSpecification {
    private int days
    //other settings?         

    public ExpirationSpecification(int days) {...}

    public boolean isSatisfied(Order order) {...}
}

public class ExpirationServiceImpl implements ExpirationService {
    //private int days;//inject using placeholder in spring
    private ConfigurationService configService;//if settings are stored in database

    ExpirationSpecification spec() {
        //return new ExpirationSpecification(days);
        return new ExpirationSpecification(configService.orderExpirationDays());
    }

    void cancel(Order order) {...}
}
```

Comment: the problem is that there are many business-specific configuration values - to give you an example how about a business term "expiration" and a system-configurable value for this eg. in days? Expiration checks should be part of the domain but for that you need to get the config value in there too.

Comment: I agree :). And I prefer to treat it as a domain concept. In your example, I would have an OrderExpirationSpecification which could be returned by a domain service. In this bounded context, it is an abstraction. How to get the days is an infrastructure concern. Furthermore, it may be required that admin should have the ability to change the days at runtime, but I think the CRUD operation should be split into another bounded context.

Comment: okay.. I only see an implementation problem here using eg. Spring or the JEE platform.. any hints how you'd approach this?

Comment: Update answer for code sample. I once was in a similar situation. This is how I did.

Comment: @Hippoom I am facing a similar problem right now. In a bounded context, I have rich domain models and many small domain-related settings. If such CRUD settings are moved into another bounded context, it will create new problems because in the UI, these settings are usually displayed alongside the values in the domain. So joining the information from multiple bounded context is troublesome.